# How we can use std::thread in QtCreator?

Tags: video-streaming, qthread, stdthread

I have mjpeg streaming code in c++11 and using std::thread. Very well designed and we are happy with it. We try to put those code inside the QtCreator, it compiled and didnt behave as expected. We couldnt see the stream in the browser. here the basic codes:

in c++11 main.cpp :

```
int main()
{
  VideoServer video;

  thread video_thread([&video]() {
    video.run();
  });

  thread capture_thread([&video]() {
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0 + cv::CAP_ANY);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
      cerr << "Error";
      return -1;
    } 
    Mat frame;
    for (;;) {
      cap.read(frame);
      video.set_image(frame);
//      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds((int)(1000 / 20)));
    }
  });


  video_thread.join();
  capture_thread.join();
}
```

videoserver.hpp

```
class VideoServer {
private:

  SimpleWeb::Server<SimpleWeb::HTTP> server;
  std::mutex image_lock;
  std::condition_variable image_notify;
  std::vector<uchar> image;
  unsigned int active = 0;

public:

  void run();
  void set_image(cv::Mat& frame);
};
```

We try to use : [robotvision](https://github.com/aanon4/RobotVision)
source code to integrate QtCreator.

in the QtCreator :
main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    DigitalClock clock;
    JVideoServer jvideo;

//    thread video_thread([&jvideo]() {
//        jvideo.run();
//        cout << "videoThread started" << endl;
//      });


    w.show();
//    video_thread.detach();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I our show_frame func in the Qt we put:

```
   jvideo.set_image(image);
```

To pass the image to the Videostreamer thread.

All is compiled without warning and software worked.

But it is very slow with this thread (2-3 times) and VideoStreamer didnt stream and we couldnt see streamed video in browser.

Any idea ? Where we should put this std::thread in the QtCreator (we are getting familiar ) ?

Thanks